# Sorting has_many through on a join table property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

Let's say I have the following in a rails4 app:

```
class Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :foo_bar
  has_many :bar, through: :foo_bar
end
```

And the foo_bar table has a "sort" column with a number. To make matters even more entertaining, the "bar" table ALSO has a "sort" column with a number. Same name as the join table sort column.  AND, this is important...

```
class Bar < AR::Base
  default_scope -> { order(:sort) }
end
```

I need to have a default scope on the association, such that:

```
foo = Foo.last
foo.bars # => List of bars, ordered by the number on the foo_bar table
```

How can I do this? It means unscoping the bar, but just the sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the sort order for collection using `order` option

```
class Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :foo_bar
  has_many :bar, -> { order('foo_bar.sort') }, through: :foo_bar
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another problem: a default scope on bar. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe there is a bug with `unscope` method in rails 4.0.X (Look at my tests - https://gist.github.com/railscard/4ab5d5996bd867c08ec0). I think your current solution is completely okay, but do not forget to refactor ordering after updating to 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
foo.bars.sort(foo_bar.position)
```

`sort` will sort the list by a given attribute, so give it the attribute on foo_bar that you wish to sort by.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. I forgot to say something critical in my question. I will edit it right now, but here it is: I need this to be a default scope on the association.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by doing this:

```
class Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :foo_bar
  has_many :bar, through: :foo_bar

  def sorted_bars
    foo_bar.map(&:bar)
  end
end
```

Because of the default scopes, this was too complicated for me. I'll still accept an answer that offers a more elegant solution :)